# How to get current folder name in gulp?

Tags: linux, node.js, gulp

In my Node.js project, I am using gulp to deploy to an array of Linux machines. I was going to use gulp-scp to file copy, but it requires I am signing in to the devices with a key and I'm using a password, so I'm using gulp-scp2 which does allow me to specify a password.
I tried to gulp.src('./') to just copy the entire folder, but going from Windows -> Linux with gulp-scp2 has an issue with '\' to '/' and thus doesn't deploy recursively. Instead, on the target machines, it builds...
myproject
\myproject\subfolder1
\myproject\subfolder2
etc.
..where the subfolders actually have the '\' characters in the name.
So my questions are...
1) Is there a better way to deploy a project
2) Is there at least a way using gulp to get the name of the current project so I can deploy files there?
Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem with trying to scp directories recursively. Did you ever find a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Try **__dirname**

> The directory name of the current module. This the same as the
>   path.dirname() of the __filename.

```
console.log(__dirname); 
// Output: /var/www/myproject.test
```